# Map Object Result

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object

I have an object in which at index 0 has an array. Inside the array I have two objects.
Using map function at obj[0] result is undefined. How can I access it?

[image]

```
  function getRowData() {

    let translationByLang = Object.values(translationArray.reduce((acc,{field,lang,text}) => {
      acc[lang] = acc[lang] || {lang}
      acc[lang][field] = text
      return acc
    },{}))

    let result = translationByLang;

    if(result.length < 2){
      let obj = {"lang":"en", "name":"Documento mancante","pdf_url":""}
      result.push(obj)
    }

    let promises=[]
      Promise.all(result).then(res => {
      promises.push(res)
    });
    return promises  

  }

  const obj = getRowData();
  console.log('typeof', typeof obj, ', obj', obj)
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you share code here?

Comment: Based on your log, the array is empty at the time of logging the array. The expanded version of your array shows you what it holds at the time of expanding, not at the time of logging, whereas the empty array on the first line is the array at the time of logging.  Are you populating your array asynchronously?

Comment: No, I am not using async to populate the array. Please check the edited question. I added the code.

Comment: You're populating your array asynchronously though with `.then()`

Comment: What is `Promise.all(result)` supposed to do? `result` is just an array of objects

Comment: Result is just an array of objects

Comment: Yeah, why are you using `Promise.all()`? That method expects and array of promises to be settled.

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `return result` directly. Seems like that's what you're expecting in `obj`.

Comment: right Adiga. Not needed. and in fact this is the problem. now its working. Thanks